# How to set Timepicker in Bootstrap daterangepicker using angular

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want to show time picker in ngx-bootstrap daterangepicker. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: i tried to add time picker in ngx-bootstrap daterangepicker. But i didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

The Timepicker control is used to select a time by a user.

In ng-bootstrap, a Timepicker can be implemented by adding the ngb-timepicker component in the template.

```
<ngb-timepicker [(ngModel)]="time"></ngb-timepicker>
<hr>
<pre>Selected time: {{time | json}}</pre>



import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-timepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: './timepicker-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdTimepickerBasic {
  time = {hour: 13, minute: 30};
}
```

Comment: without adding the ngb-timepicker  ,a is it possible ?
like using "withTimepicker" property in ngx-bootsrap daterangepicker